Does Javascript share strings?
If I write
let x="hello"
let y="hello"

does Javascript make two references to the same string, or does it create two separate strings that happen to have the same content?
This first occurred to me when thinking about a micro-optimization. I had about 40 occurrences of an identical, 12 character string and I was wondering if that would take 12 bytes (plus whatever overhead) or 480. I quickly realized that was trivial either way so even if I modified the code to guarantee it's the same chunk of memory, so what? But one could imagine cases where there could me a million copies of a 1000-character string, so it's one of those things that would just be good to know.
It also led me to the broader question: How could I find out? In some languages I could dump the value of the reference and see if the two are the same, but I don't know any way to do that in Javascript. And of course if I write "if (x==y)", that's going to be true because the contents are the same, so it would prove nothing.

you can change one and see if the other changes

@ITgoldman Strings are immutable in JS. How would you change one?

i see your point. and since they are immutable it might make sense to keep one copy in memory. but immutability is the answer, and i am talking about a way to find it out by checking if x and y reference the same thing.

@ITgoldman And the question is: how would you do that? You can test them for equality, you can’t test whether they reference the same place in memory.

how would you prove that strings are immutable?

@ITgoldman Try mutating one…‽

@deceze Not sure how that would prove anything. If I say x="hello"; x=x+", world", have I changed the string or created a new string? The answer, of course, is that I've created a new string, but I don't know how you'd prove that.

@Jay = always assigns a new value to a variable. It cannot mutate anything existing. You’re looking for some equivalent of Array.prototype.push or such for string objects, which mutates a string in place. (Hint: you won’t find any such methods.)

Alternative approach: let a = 'foo'; let b = a;. Now try to do anything to a that mutates it in such a way that console.log(a, b) both output the changed value.

@deceze Sure, if you could, that would prove that strings are mutable. But if you can't, that doesn't really prove that strings are immutable. It just proves that one way or another, JS is smart enough to handle it. My point isn't to debate whether JS strings are mutable. There are a million places where it's documented that they aren't. My point is that I have a hard time coming up with an experiment with JS code that would prove this. I think you'd have to hack into the infrastructure.

Well, if you hack deep enough, you can simply modify the raw memory, making anything mutable. The point is, plain user facing Javascript exposes not a single method that modifies string objects in place. That is basically all the proof you need.
